# Is it possible to get 4 fields by their positions, but with random id?

Tags: mysql, random

If someone can help me with this. I'm trying to get 4 random fields form mysql table by position, the problem is that I need to have always 4 types and they to be random here is a sql http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2c76f/1

so the result should be always position 1,2,3,4 but with random id, is it possible to do this with one query or I have to have 4 deferent by any type?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you cannot effectively use an `ORDER BY` clause in the same query with a `GROUP BY` (meaning that you cannot order records before grouping them), you could do something like this ([here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/392d3/10) is the fiddle):

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM banners ORDER BY RAND() // shuffle the records
) AS banners GROUP BY position ORDER BY position // group and order them by position
```

This has the advantage that you don't have to hardcode the available positions. If you decide to add another position (5, 6, etc), this will still work. Otherwise, @Ronak Shah's UNION solution is simpler and more efficient.

Comment: Thanks. but I think Alex always wants result in position 1,2,3,4 that means he always wants records with these 4 position and in your suggestion query can skip it

Comment: @RonakShah what do you mean "skip it"?  Victor why 3 selects? only 2 are enough

Comment: the outer-most select is not needed just put the `ORDER BY position` after the `GROUP BY position`

Comment: @Sharky You can't ORDER BY in the same query with a GROUP BY, I specifically mentioned this in my answer.

Comment: @Sharky.. say you want only 4 records and if you use Limit 4 just after than ORDER BY RAND() then It can skip records but at very last if you use limit 4 then its perfect

Comment: @RonakShah oh, he wants just 4 records, yes, you can add a limit. I still say your solution is simpler though.

Comment: @Sharky I apologize, I was being a smart-ass, while I was the one in the wrong. You are, of course, right. Only two queries are necessary, not three. I have edited my answer.

Comment: @VictorStanciu, I have give you upvote, your solution looks perfect if Alex wants to make it generic and not bound with any where clause.. great stuff bro..

Comment: Please note: This will ONLY work if you have MySQL's group by "extensions" ON. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html

Answer (score 1):

Try below:

```
select * from (SELECT * FROM (`banners`) WHERE `published` =1  ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) A
    Union ALL
select * from (SELECT * FROM (`banners`) WHERE `published` =2  ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) B
    Union ALL
select * from (SELECT * FROM (`banners`) WHERE `published` =3  ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) C
    Union ALL
select * from (SELECT * FROM (`banners`) WHERE `published` =4  ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) D
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do. Tested.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/392d3/11

```
  SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM banners WHERE position IN(1,2,3,4) ORDER BY RAND()
  ) AS banners GROUP BY position ORDER BY position;
```

you can omit the `WHERE` clause to work with every position available.